# SSIS: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.Char[]'

Tags: c#, sql-server, postgresql, ssis

I am doing data integration from SQL Server 2008 R2 to PostgreSQL 9.5.

I have table with following details:

**Table**: In SQL Server

```
create table test
(
    cola int,
    colb numeric(18,0),
    colc varchar(50),
    cold datetime,
    cole bit,
    colf char(1)
);
```

**Table**: In PostgreSQL

```
create table test
(
    cola int,
    colb numeric(18,0),
    colc varchar(50),
    cold timestamp(0),
    cole boolean,
    colf char(1)
);
```

Package details:

Source : OLE DB Source (SQL Server)

Data Conversion : On column `colc` to DT_WSTR

Destination : ADO NET Destination (PostgreSQL)

Error Details:

> [ADO NET Destination [129]] Error: An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.Char[]'.

Data Conversion:
[image]

Mapping:
[image]

Sample Data: In SQL Server

```
insert into test1 values(1,NULL,'z','2017-02-12 12:21:50.000',1,'C');
insert into test1 values(2,1344,'Xuz','2017-02-12 12:21:50.000',0,'D');
insert into test1 values(3,NULL,'T','2017-02-12 12:21:50.000',1,'E');
```

Error:
[image]

**Input and Output properties**:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Mak! What is the datatype of column Colc displayed when you are mapping the source and destination. Also, did you try adding a data conversion task to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Vasanth, Data type of column `colc` is `varchar(50)` and I have added data conversion task for this column which is `Unicode string [DT_WSTR]`.

Comment: can you provide a snapchot of the package? and columns mapping on the ado destination?

Comment: @Hadi, Please check the edited post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following data conversion works fine to me.

**Data Conversion**: I have converted `colb` from `NUMERIC` to `CHAR` in the data conversion part and works fine to me.

```
colb string[DT_STR]
```

[image]

This conversion looks very strange to me but its working fine that's matter.

Let me know if I am wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Your column mapping looks fine, you have to check your columns data type using the advanced editor.

Right click on `Ado.net Destination` --> `Input and Output Columns` Tab --> check that columns data type are defined correctly.

*Side Note: Why converting `colb` if it is a numeric column*

Comment: Columns data types are correctly defined in `Input and Output properties`. I have added screenshots in my post, please have a look.

Comment: Converting `colb` is one of the testing for the seeking solution.